# Gsconnect lack of notification icon in gnome panel

Tags: gnome-shell, notification, gnome-shell-extension, kde-connect

I have Ubuntu 19.10 and Gsconnect v30. Some time ago notification icon on GNOME disappeared.
When I turn on Gsconnect from Ubuntu Software its works, my phone is connected.
[image]

Any idea how to restore notification button?
I tried change between Panel and User Menu.

My log

```
GSConnect Version: 30
GSConnect Install: user
GJS: 15801
XDG_SESSION_TYPE: wayland
GDMSESSION: ubuntu-wayland
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Logs begin at Tue 2020-01-21 09:23:44 CET, end at Tue 2020-01-21 09:43:40 CET. --
sty 21 09:43:32 dbus-daemon[10000]: [session uid=1000 pid=10000] Activating service name='org.gnome.gedit' requested by ':1.180' (uid=1000 pid=12021 comm="gjs /home/maczet/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensio" label="unconfined")
sty 21 09:43:32 dbus-daemon[10000]: [session uid=1000 pid=10000] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.gedit'
sty 21 09:43:40 gnome-shell[10063]: libinput error: client bug: timer event4 debounce short: offset negative (-1ms)
```

Comment: Extensions were turned off in GNOME Tweaks. https://github.com/andyholmes/gnome-shell-extension-gsconnect/issues/752

Comment: Sometimes extensions do NOT load after logging in in Ubuntu 19.10. I do not know whether this is a known problem (bug) in 19.10. But, the workaround is to start **GNOME Tweaks** and re-enable **Extensions** manually. Also, try to keep your extensions up-to-date.

Comment: Check LookingGlass Alt+F2-lg > extensions > errors you may see something there. Also could you try login using Xorg (i see you are using Wayland)